# Moving from JBoss 4.2.x to ....?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

The company where I work has its main application deployed and running in JBoss 4.2.3 (ejb2.1 spec). It also uses JBPM 3.x extensively. Each customer has its own server, and the application is accessed through HTTP (front end in Struts2).

I was tasked to look at what we could do to set foot in the 2020 decade...

At first glance, the migration from 4.2.x to JBoss EAP7 seems like it would involve a lot of work (and trial and error from what I gather...). I don't really see a clear path for the migration, except a few posts mentioning that it may be easier to move from JBoss 4.x to 5, and then move to 7.x from there.

Even so, I am not 100% we would benefit that much from staying in that ecosystem (most of our knowledge will be obsolete, since configurations, folder structure, annotations, etc. most probably have changed a lot since then), and I am afraid that we may end up wasting a lot of time trying to make it work and end up rewriting most of what we have. I was wondering how you would tackle this in 2022?

Would you suggest staying with JBoss? Move to another (better?) server technology (where JBPM could also be deployed)? Use this opportunity to rethink the architecture completely (ex.: go from a monolithic app to something a bit more fractured into micro-services, etc.)?

Note: We will also need to continue supporting currently existing data (customers' JBPM processes will be rolled out to the latest version gradually). For this, I was thinking we could add a REST layer to the 4.x server, that would be used by the new server when appropriate. We could also probably do something like this for most operations (not just JBPM related) I guess, as we gradually integrate/add them to the new tech.? Would that make sense?

I know it's hard to give a complete answer without knowing all the details, but I am asking anyway to get a pulse or to have people share their experiences if they had to go through a similar thing. As of now, anything is open. We are trying to see what kind of options we have and how much investment each would require.

Comment: Whatever you decide to do, it's going to be difficult and a lot of work... you're probably using a really old version of Java too.

Comment: Recently we moved from JBoss 4.2.3 to Open Liberty. It was the easiest application server to migrate, because it was very flexible. Probably you will need some changes in the descriptors, but overall it should be easy

Comment: @Jesper It is what I imagine too! And yes, we are stuck with JDK8 yes. Fun times ahead!

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueHupner Did not have a chance to look into this one yet. I will look it up. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: There are free migration tools that will speed up the migration to Liberty (Transformation Advisor, Migration toolkit for Eclipse, Migration toolkit for binaries that works on ears/wars/jars). Tools scan your apps and tell what you need to change to move.